# Using wildcards on both sides of Subsequent-sibling Combinator selector

Tags: css

I'm thinking it's not possible to do what I'd like, but maybe someone knows a solution...

This solution needs to be pure HTML and CSS. No active content.

The following code is part of an image gallery with thumbnails. When a thumbnail is clicked on, the related larger image displays. Also, the clicked thumbnail gets a border around it since it is the active selection.

The CSS rule works in long form - by specifying each numbered element in the left and right side selectors.

This works fine. When a thumbnail is clicked it gets a border applied to it:

```
.pics.gallery #slide0:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic0,
.pics.gallery #slide1:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic1,
.pics.gallery #slide2:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic2,
.pics.gallery #slide3:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic3,
.pics.gallery #slide4:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic4,
.pics.gallery #slide5:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic5,
.pics.gallery #slide6:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic6,
.pics.gallery #slide7:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic7,
.pics.gallery #slide8:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic8,
.pics.gallery #slide9:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic9,
.pics.gallery #slide10:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic10,
.pics.gallery #slide11:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic11,
.pics.gallery #slide12:checked ~ div .thumb label.pic12 {
    border: 1px solid #333 !important;
}
```

I would like to replace the above multiline selector with something like the following for the purpose of brevity, as well as allowing more than just 12 images:

```
.pics.gallery [id^='slide']:checked ~ div .thumb label[class^='pic'] {
    border: 1px solid #333 !important;
}
```

What happens with the short rule is that all thumbnails get a border around them. I understand why as it is written - if any of `#slide?` are checked, all of `.pic?` are getting a border applied. Though the long form version of the rule works fine.

I have a working solution - I am only trying to keep the CSS rule as short as possible.

**HTML (partial)**

```
<div class="row pics gallery m-0">

  <input name="switch" id="slide0" class="anchor slide" type="radio" checked="checked">
  <input name="switch" id="slide1" class="anchor slide" type="radio">

  <!-- Large Image -->
  <div class="col-md-9 p-0">
    <ul>
      <li class="pic0 img slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000/ffffff/999?text=Graphic-1(1000x1000)" class="img-responsive">
      </li>
      <li class="pic1 img slide">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000/ffffff/999?text=Graphic-2(1000x1000)" class="img-responsive">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- End Large Image -->

  <!-- Thumbnails -->
  <div class="col-md-3 p-2">
    <div class="thumb">
      <span class="text-black-50" style="font-weight: 100; font-size: 14px;">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Click Thumbnails to Enlarge
      </span>
      <br>

      <div class="row m-0">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 p-2 text-center">
          <label class="pic0 col-xs-3" for="slide0"><span class="anchor"></span>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100/ffffff/999?text=Thumb-1(100x100)" class="img-fluid">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 p-2 text-center">
          <label class="pic1 col-xs-3" for="slide1"><span class="anchor"></span>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100/ffffff/999?text=Thumb-2(100x100)" class="img-fluid">
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Thumbnails -->

</div>
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to know what's supposed to happen here without a description. One thing: I'm not sure why you're using `[id^='slide']` instead of, say, `input.slide`. You could also just give all of the `label` elements an additional `pic` class and use `.pic` instead of `[class^='pic']`.

Comment: Could you please add a short description of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @SalmanA I re-edited the question to explain it better. My initial question got jumbled by an edit from someone. Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: I don't think it is possible like _select (n+x)th sibling of nth checked item_. I would suggest that you re-arrange the html markup. Is re-arranging html an option?

Comment: @SalmanA I could restructure the HTML if there's a solution. What would you change?

Comment: I would place checkbox next to image and use `input:checked + thumbnail { }`